# How do you run a play command from outside the project folder?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

Is it possible to call play commands for a given project/folder? I mean without being in the project folder?
For example :

```
play dist /path/to/a/given/folder
play dist /path/to/another/folder
```

Especially usefull in CI.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way I can imagine is just rely on bash functionality:

```
cd /path/to/a/given/folder; pwd; play dist; cd -
cd /path/to/another/folder; pwd; play dist; cd -
```

Of course you don't need to write it again and again. You can just write small bash script for that job. Then it will be `one-line` call.

Comment: Yes, that's what I do for the moment. I was looking for alternatives without `cd`.